# How generate a sequence of integer using template works here

Tags: c++, templates

I see this code in gtest source file. this snippet is used to generate a template whose template variable is a sequence of integer. can anybody explain how this works?

```
template <size_t... Is> struct int_pack { typedef int_pack type; };

template <class Pack, size_t I>
struct append;
template <size_t... Is, size_t I>
struct append<int_pack<Is...>, I> : int_pack<Is..., I> {};

template <size_t C>
struct make_int_pack : append<typename make_int_pack<C - 1>::type, C - 1> {};
template <> struct make_int_pack<0> : int_pack<> {};
```

we can use `make_int_pack<5>()` to generate a class instance (`int_pack<0,1,2,3,4>()`) which is further used to extract 0,1,2,3,4 to do something.

Comment: Notice that, since C++14, we have [`std::index_sequence`/`std::make_integer_sequence `](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

Comment: thanks @Jarod42, I also want to know how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **construction** is done with recursive substitution:

`make_int_pack<5>` derives from `append<typename make_int_pack<5-1>::type,5-1>`.

But `make_int_pack<5-1>::type` is `make_int_pack<4>::type`.

But `make_int_pack<4>::type` is the definition from `append<typename make_int_pack<4-1>::type,4-1>`, and so on.

So `make_int_pack<5>` derives from

```
  append<append<append<append<append<int_pack<>,0>,1>,2>,3>,4>
```

, which derives from `int_pack<0,1,2,3,4>`.

To **use** this `int_pack` we have to do something like pattern matching (c++11).

```
template<class T>struct test{};

template<size_t ... Is>
struct test<int_pack<Is...>>{
    // use template parameter pack
};
```

We could then use the static members of `test<make_int_pack<5>>` as result of some compiletime compilation or complex type construction.

Another possible way is to have

```
template<size_t... Is>
size_t test_fun(int_pack<Is...>);
```

,which would be called like `test_fun(make_int_pack<5>());`

Edit:

> I'm wondering why there's two append struct, what's the difference
>   between them?

You want to be able to write `append<int_pack<0,1,2,3>,42>`. Therefor `append` has to take two template parameters. That is your first declaration.

```
template<class T,size_t i> struct append{};
```

But actually you do not need the type `int_pack<0,1,2,3>` but the template paramter pack used. In c++ we have **partial template specialization**. If the type `T` happends to be an `int_pack` we use the special (second) declaration. In this way we can kind of pattern match the templated type `T` and get the template parameters used do define the `int_pack`.

```
template<size_t ... Is,size_t i>
struct append<int_pack<Is...>,i> : int_pack<Is...,i>{};
```

> what's the meaning of append,0> ?

This will fall in the second case. We have an empty template parameter pack, since the brackets are empty `int_pack<>`. So we derive from `int_pack<0>` and therefor our `append<int_pack<>,0>::type` is `int_pack<0>`.

So in summary:
look at **template parameter packs** and **partial template specialization**.
When working with types it is basicly just substitution of expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm wondering why there's two append struct, what's the difference between them. what's the meaning of append<int_pack<>,0> ? Any reply is appreciated.